# Object overlap logic

Tags: actionscript-3

Below is the code for objects being added to stage and then checking to see if the newly added object is overlapping previous objects. The problem is when the player is moving, objects on stage will randomly move because of the constant generation of random objects.This is called in an enter frame timer

```
if(onStageCount < 15){
        var Square:MovieClip;
        Square = new mcSquare();
        Square.x = Math.random() * 1000 + ((Math.abs(_boundaries.x) + (stage.stageWidth)));
        Square.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight/2.5 + (stage.stageHeight/2.5);
        ObjectArray.push(Square);
        onStageCount += 1;
    }
    for (var i in ObjectArray){
        for (var a in ObjectArray){
            if(ObjectArray[i].hitTestObject(ObjectArray[a]) && a != i){ChildrenColliding = true;}
            while(ChildrenColliding){
            ObjectArray[i].x += (ObjectArray[a].width + 75);
            ObjectArray[i].y += (ObjectArray[a].height + 40);
            ChildrenColliding = false;
                if(ObjectArray[a].hitTestObject(ObjectArray[i]) && a != i){ChildrenColliding = true;}
            }
        }
        _boundaries.addChild(ObjectArray[i]);
    }
```

Comment: So what kind of solution are you hoping for?

Comment: I think this is where I am struggling. I'm not sure, all I know is that the code above creates a very "choppy" generation of platforms, I guess I would want it to generate a few on screen initially and then after that only generate them off the stage and check the whole collisions and then slide onto stage already not overlapping each other...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code will generate one platform every time it's called. If you want several to appear at once (i.e. in a single timer event), you could change the `if` at the beginning to a `while`. That will make it generate platforms until there are 15 every time the function is called.

You don't need to check every possible collision whenever a platform is placed- the ones that are already there are fine. You can just use one `for ... in` loop, testing each object against `Square` and moving `Square` if necessary. That should prevent objects from "moving randomly" during platform generation. Though it might be better to regenerate the position in the same way as you do the first time instead of offsetting them by a specific amount.

To generate some platforms on the screen, the easiest way is to use a different range of x values the first time you generate platforms. You could also generate them as usual, and move them forward by some amount when the game starts. Though, there are a lot of approaches, and it's hard to say which is the best without seeing how the entire game works.